# Always gor this error: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: php, wordpress

On client end shows Internal server error.
I am using wordpress, and the Internal server error is already been a long time(almost 1 month), and every time, it will be fixed When I resave the permalinks in wordpress permalink setting,, but after that the issue comes again within 1 or 2 days.
I also have tried copy the whore server files to a new server when the issue exsits, but the new server works well (no need resave permalinks).

In this case, what should be the most likely problem?

I have tried delete the .htaccess file, and resave permalinks, so Wordpress will generate a new and clean .htaccess.

I have tried increase the php memory limit and wordpress memory limit to 512M.

Anyone can help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Check out

> wp-config.php

If you have one or both of these statements set:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

These defines should, if set, usually both be set to the *https://yourdomain.com*

**Solution 2:**

**Finding Redirects in the Database:**
Check your base/home URLs in the database as well. Go to your Control Panel and under the database tab you can find a link to phpMyAdmin.

The database log in credentials should be an email that get sent when creating a site/database.
Then navigate to the table where the base/home URLs is stored.
In WordPress this is stored at table *wp_options*, and under option_name you will find the value *siteurl* and *home*.

You can also use WP-CLI with SSH by running this command in the ~/public directory.

```
# For site URL
wp option get siteurl

# For home URL
wp option get home
```

**Solution 3:**

**Deactivate plugins :**
Deactivate all the plugin one by one and check your problem is fixed or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replying, I have found the solution, after I added the memory limit rule to .htaccess, the problems seems got fixed.